# all scheduled reports are deleted after server restarting pentaho bi server

Tags: pentaho

I had a list of scheduled reports running in Pentaho bi server. every time I restart Pentaho server all the scheduled job are deleted.
When I check in Catalina here in what I got:

Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.scheduler2.SchedulerException: Quartz failed to list jobs.
        at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.QuartzScheduler.getJobs(QuartzScheduler.java:481)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.services.SchedulerService.getJobs(SchedulerService.java:503)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.SchedulerResource.getJobs(SchedulerResource.java:415)